# How to update email 'To' field with email address from a field in Access form?

Tags: vba, email, ms-access, outlook

I have everything working to send an email via an Access command button. However, the displayed email address is incorrect.

```vb
Private Sub cmdSendEmail_Click()
    Dim EmailApp, NameSpace, EmailSend As Object

    Set EmailApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set NameSpace = EmailApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set EmailSend = EmailApp.CreateItem(0)

    EmailSend.To = [emailadd] '[emailadd] is the field on the form where the button is located

    EmailSend.Subject = [Forms]![WorkordersVR]![Project] & " - " & [Forms]![WorkordersVR]![JobNumber]
    EmailSend.Body = "Hello," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        "The project" & " " & [Forms]![WorkordersVR]![Project] & " " & "is ready for pickup." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        "Thank you!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        "Person sending email here" & vbCrLf & _

    EmailSend.Display

    Set EmailApp = Nothing
    Set NameSpace = Nothing
    Set EmailSend = Nothing

End Sub
```

What ends up in the displayed email To is:
"fred@aplace.com#fred@aplace.com#"

How do I get fred@aplace.com?

Comment: Email is saved in field as an Access hyperlink structure. Why is it saved like that? As is, have to use string manipulation functions to extract left part up to the first # character.

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out. Brain didn't even consider extracting/trimming the email address line. I used:  EmailSend.To = Left([emailadd], InStr([emailadd], "#") - 1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use string functions available in VBA to get a substring until the # symbol in the string. For example, the [InStr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function) function returns a number specifying the position of the first occurrence of one string within another.

Also I'd suggest using the [Recipients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.recipients) property of the `MailItem` class which returns a `Recipients` collection that represents all the recipients for the Outlook item. Then I'd suggest using the [Recipient.Resolve](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.resolve) method which attempts to resolve a `Recipient` object against the Address Book.

For example:

```
Sub CreateStatusReportToBoss() 
 Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient 
 
 Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
 Set myRecipient = myItem.Recipients.Add("email") 
 
 myRecipient.Resolve

 If(myRecipient.Resolved) Then  
   myItem.Subject = "Status Report" 
   myItem.Display 
 End If

End Sub
```